# Position of android app shortcut on home screen

Tags: android, positioning, shortcut, homescreen, android-launcher

I have to create my android application shortcut and put it at a particular position on home screen.

I am able to successfully able to create the shortcut for the application by the following code-

```
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "customizeScreenLayout");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so don't duplicate
    getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

What can I add to the above code so that I can place the shortcut at a particular position in the home screen(i.e., at a particular x,y coordinate)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there's nothing you can add to designate a particular position. Looking at [the sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher2/+/684476f9a4fb374d026f17487cbf51c391223cb0/src/com/android/launcher2/InstallShortcutReceiver.java), it appears that the algorithm for positioning new shortcuts is hard-wired into `InstallShortcutReceiver`.

Just out of curiousity, if there was a way to do what you wanted, what would you want to happen if a shortcut was already at the designated position? How would you handle different screen sizes, where the designated position might not exist on the home page?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the prompt reply. The problem that I have posted here is just a part of a project where I want to make an application which checks all the installed apps on the system and create short-cuts for them. After that checks the x, y coordinates from the database where we need to position the apps and puts it over there.

Now suppose designating a particular position was possible, what I intended to do was-
1) Uninstall all the shortcuts
2) And then, install the shortcuts of different apps at the required positions.

Also, assumption here is that I am dealing with a fixed screen size and designated positions always exist.

Let me know if you find something or if you need additional information.